# Azure Data Explorer C# querying and ORM

Tags: entity-framework, azure-data-explorer, kql

I looked into querying data from DotNet and found: `https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-samples-dotnet` samples.

I see no ORM examples there and this got me to try something myself

```cs
public class KustoContext : DbContext
{
    public KustoContext(KustoConfiguration kustoConfiguration)
      : base(new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(kustoConfiguration.ClusterUri, kustoConfiguration.DatabaseName)
          .WithAadApplicationKeyAuthentication(kustoConfiguration.ClientId, kustoConfiguration.ClientSecret, kustoConfiguration.TenantId)
          .ConnectionString)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<SomeEntity> SomeEntities{ get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately, I get an error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Data.dll
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Keyword not supported: 'application client id'.

This makes sense, I guess I need a provider for adx, but I couldn't find a NuGet package for that.

Ideally, I would like to use Entity Framework with Azure Data Explorer. Is this possible? Are there any available samples?

**UPDATE**: are there any alternatives for Entity Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ideally, I would like to use Entity Framework with Azure Data Explorer. Is this possible? Are there any available samples?

I don't believe anyone has written an Entity Framework provider for Azure Data Explorer.

Comment: Is there a day announced/proposed by the ADX Team when they will work on one? Or is it in their roadmap at all?